# Android how to create tiling wallpaper image?

Tags: java, android, image

I have an image of a pattern and I want to create a larger image from this by tilling it so that the user can apply it as a wallpaper. How would I go about doing this?

The pattern tile can be of varying dimensions.

I also want to be doing this with a color palette so I have 5 different colours and I want to make a wallpaper that consisted of thick stripes of these colors...not too sure how I should be doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Snake sample has an example of how to do this
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Snake/src/com/example/android/snake/TileView.html

Comment: thanks for the link. had a quick look and it seems like they are creating a view based on a tiling image...how would I set this view as the phone wallpaper? I thought you can only set it from a bitmap?

Comment: oh I'm sorry I misread your question, you would want to use photoshop for that I guess... Or make a live wallpaper.